# magento setup problem

Tags: magento

when i started to configure magento and click next to create the admin then apache is shut down. I am using xampp as my local setup.

Comment: Check your log files for errors, maybe you memory_limit php setting is to low or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xampp on windows, remember that Magento is not supported on windows. Check if your Xampp install has all the modules required in [Magento specs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get to the setup program again by wiping out your database and deleting the app/etc/local.xml file

This should at least let you run your installer again and hopefully it works out better for you.

Make sure your php.ini file allows for plenty of memory usage and a long enough time to run.

I have not heard of Magento not running on Windows, but frankly it would not surprise me.  PHP runs so much better on a Linux system.  If you need help getting one setup I can recommend using VirtualBox to virtualize the entire server. If you need help with getting that setup just holler.